# How to access my ubuntu 20.04 files from windows 10 wsl2 for development purposes?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I installed ubuntu on my windows 10 machine using WSL2. What is the best practice method to use both windows and my WSL2 ubuntu together?

For example: Where to initiate my git repo? on windows or ubuntu? How to access my ubuntu files from windows? (or the other way around?)

Thanks!

Comment: While this is a duplicate question, I prefer it since it doesn't have any old, outdated, and (most importantly) dangerous answers like some of the others I've found.

Answer (score 1):

- I recommend initiating the git repos in the very environment you intend to build the software.
- You can access your Windows files under Ubuntu from the automatically mounted drives `/mnt/c/`, `/mnt/d/`, etc.
- You can access your Ubuntu files under Ubuntu from `\\wsl$`. Note that doing so used to entail risks but according to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/ it doesn't anymore.
- For your reference WSL integrates neatly with Visual Studio Code, see for example https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-vscode.